# Creating static custom URL's for sharepoint 2010 website

Tags: custom, url

We running website based on shaerpoint 2010, and we planning to upgrade soon to SP 2013, the website is relatively large, and includes many complex section including e-commerce.

2 years back we change the CMS new website had different URL's so this dropped our SEO ranking, and we had to rebuild it back again. my objective is to find solution that i can create manually url's for specific key pages for example :

www.xyz.com/About-us/Aboutus.php

becomes after SEF

www.xyz.com/about.html

I'm looking for Search Engine Friendly solution (SEF) similar to sh404sef, that can do the following:

1. Force URL's to lowercase
2. Force either www or non-www (if used, make sure that plugin "System - Cache" is set as last, or it may not work)
3. Set a suffix for your URL's. Default is .html, but this does not make sense, so I always remove this.
4. Create short-URL's as an alias for long ones. Unless needed, switch it off.
5. Force non-SEF to SEF or not
6. Use title or alias for URL's
7. Include category structure in URL's or not and if set, how many levels deep
8. Some settings for page-titles: with or without site-name or any other prefix/suffix
9. Set Canonical URL's

Please advise if there are solution for this issue.

thanking you.